# Condensing an array of hashes within that same array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Basically I'm trying to condense this one array of hashes with the same value into another array. I'm new to Ruby and I'm trying to change this

```
fruit = [
 {type: 'grape', color: 'purple' },
 {type: 'grape', shape: 'round'},
 {type: 'grape', size: 'small'},
 {type: 'apple', color: 'red'},
 {type: 'apple', size: 'med'},

]
```

to this:

```
fruit = [
  {type: 'grape', color: 'purple', shape: 'round', size: 'small'}
  {type: 'apple', color: 'red', size: 'med'}
]
```

Any help?

Comment: What are the values of `grape`, `purple`, etc? Don't introduce methods or variables without explanation.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, mistyped. All of those are strings -- I'll have to retype.

Comment: Question is not clear. What is the rule that excludes `{size: "small"}` from the hash with `{type: "grape"}`?

Comment: Sorry, again, mistyped. No rule, should be in the output. Basically I need to condense the key/value pairs that are in many hashes with the same type. So for all the hashes with type 'grape' need to be condensed into one hash with type 'grape' holding all of the other key/value pairs stored in associating with type 'grape'. Sorry if my post was unclear.

Comment: @mohawkjohn for the record, this was my closest attempt.   

new_fruit = fruit.group_by {|h| h[:type]}.map do |k,v|
   v.inject({}) {h.merge v}
end

Comment: Great. You should post that along with the question next time so we know enough about your skill level to be able to help you. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fruit.group_by{|h| h[:type]}.values.map{|a| a.inject(:merge)}
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    :type  => "grape",
    :color => "purple",
    :shape => "round",
    :size  => "small"
  },
  {
    :type  => "apple",
    :color => "red",
    :size  => "med"
  }
]
```

Comment: It'd be awesome if we asked new users to show what they've already tried / put a little more effort into explaining our answers.

Comment: This works! Thank you! I obviously need to do more work on method chaining and manipulating arrays/hashes!

Comment: @mohawkjohn You mean "effort into explaining their questions"? If so, I agree. I sometimes keep my answer deleted for a while until the OP shows effort.

Comment: @mohawkjohn Yeah I've tried using both inject and merge but I just wasn't able to wrap my head around the ordering. Thanks again.

Comment: @sawa Sorry for the typos. I've been plugging away / researching this problem for quite a while now. Since I usually like to solve problems on my own - do my own research, etc., asking a question on Stackoverflow is usually a last resort, which I guess leaves me error-prone because I get a bit careless typing my question.

Comment: @user1717344 It is more important to do things accurately than to learn new methods/features.

Comment: @sawa sorry to have annoyed you.